# delete project with modal in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, routes, bootstrap-modal

I have a delete button beside my projects that shows a popup modal for confirmation whenever the button is clicked on. I want the yes button in the modal to then delete the project whenever this button is clicked on.

I'm calling the modal into the projects/show view with @include. The modal does appear when the button is clicked using the following jquery but the yes button when pressed is not deleting the project.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

   $(".delete").on("submit", function(e){

       e.preventDefault();

       $('#myModal').modal('show'); 


    });

});
```

The delete button beside projects:

```
  {!! Form::open(['route' => ['projects.destroy', $projects->id], 'class' => 'delete', 'method' => 'DELETE']) !!}

           {!!Form::button('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-md', 'type' => 'submit'])!!}

            {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Modal code:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="myModalLabel">Delete Confirmation</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body text-center">
        Are you sure you want to delete this project?
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" id="delete-btn" class="btn btn-default" >Yes</button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

ProjectController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\project;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Session;

class ProjectsController extends Controller
{

 public function destroy($id){

        $project = Project::find($id);

        $project->delete();

        Session::flash('success', 'The project was successfully deleted!');

        return redirect()->route('projects.show', $project->project_id);

    }

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The problem is whenever I click the yes button in the modal it does nothing and I'm looking this button to delete the project.

Comment: You're referencing a route `'projects.destroy'`, what does that route do?

Comment: @Loek this route is in the projectscontroller which is set up to delete.

Comment: Ah, your JavaScript is intercepting your request to the route and instead shows a modal box. So effectivly, nothing is happening. https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/ I don't know enough JavaScript to give you working code, but you should make sure that when the submit button in the modal is clicked, the request is actually reaching the route

Comment: @Loek I know and need help with it lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the submit button in your modal to this:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['projects.destroy', $projects->id], 'class' => 'delete', 'method' => 'DELETE']) !!}

<button type="submit" id="delete-btn" class="btn btn-default" >Yes</button>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The best solution is to remove your implementation of the delete button you have now and make it a normal button. Let that button pop up the modal and replace your "Yes" button with an actual remove button like I did above.

Comment: I have added that code to my modal and i get an undefined variable - projects. Even though I have included the modal file into the show.blade.php file.

Comment: Oh wait you're including the modal ofcourse. If you copy the modal to your loaded view?

Comment: No problem! I'm sure there is a way to make your modal includable, but I can't help you there ;)

Comment: I have a quick question. Even though it deletes the project it deletes in the wrong order lol it doesn't delete by the project id ??

Comment: How can i pass the id through.

Comment: Argh crap. That's why I always use `confirm()` instead of modals. Is the usage of modals absolutely necessary? Else I can update my answer with using `confirm()`, which is a working solution I have used multiple time myself

Comment: I know how to work confirm() just thought modal was nicer lol

Comment: Ah okay. I know enough HTML + JavaScript to get myself out of most situations, but this is a bit beyond me unfortunately.