# (Laravel) Confirmation modal on delete button

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I have a view which display a table of users from the database and the last column has delete button on it which currently work fine for me but i want to display confirmation model and when the user click on Delete button it will delete the selected use

This is the current code for delete button which is work fine:

```
<a href="{{ route('deleteUser', ['user_id' => $user->id]) }}"><button type="button" class="btn mr-0 mb-0 btn-outline-primary btn-sm"><i class="icon-trash3"></i></button></a>
```

Now i used this modal which i have to click on delete button in order to delete the selected user

```
<div class="modal fade text-xs-left" id="iconModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2"><i class="icon-warning2"></i> Confirmation Message</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Are you sure that you want to <strong>Delete</strong> this user ?</p>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn grey btn-outline-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </
```

Comment: You may wish to consider `bootbox` which already has this function. refer to http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html#bb-confirm-dialog

Comment: I don't want to use a lot of extra library unless it really needed My main problem is that how i can only pass the user_id when click on Delete button on the model which direct me to deleteUser route in UsersController to process user_id and delete the selected user.

Comment: This should help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635949/delete-project-with-modal-in-laravel

Comment: That won't work since i don't know the code structure will be and if the model out side the loop how i would pass user id to it ?

Comment: Ok, with more tests i was able to make the model delete the user but i have my main problem again which is if i put the model inside the loop to display users info it will always delete the first user and if i put the model outside the loop it will always delete the last user so how i can fix that ?

Comment: Code1 https://codeshare.io/GADXgr    Code2 https://codeshare.io/G714xj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to generate a modal for each users. Just build a single modal and use data- attributes for dynamic parts.

So, as minimal, use data- attribute for every button, e.g. 
data-user-id="{{ }}" to use in form action:

```
<a href="#" class="btn mr-0 mb-0 btn-outline-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteUserConfirmation" data-user-id="{{ $user->id }}"><i class="icon-trash3"></i></a>
```

In the modal window use a form with delete method:

```
<form id="deleteUserForm" method="POST">
{{ method_field("DELETE") }}
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">DELETE</button>
</form>
```

In script use:

```
<script>
  $('#deleteUserForm').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
  $('#deleteUserForm').attr('action', '/user/' + button.data('user-id'));
});
</script>
```

In route use:

```
Route::delete('/user/{user}', 'UserController@destroy');
```

P.S. You may also use other data attributes ti use dynamically e.g. data-user-name="{{ }}" to show the user's name will be deleted.

Comment: Ok, i have done what you suggest to do but i get an error "Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message"   https://codeshare.io/5PXkqd

Comment: if you are using {{ method_field("DELETE") }} in the form, you MUST use Route::delete() in your route for the form submit route.

Comment: as you can see in the code below the route is this: Route::delete('delete/user/{user_id}', 'UsersController@deleteUserId')->name('deleteUser');

Comment: The reason of MethodNotAllowedHttpException is the form action method and the method in route does not match. If you are sure that your route is method is delete(), make sure that your form is sending $_POST['_method'] = 'DELETE'. {{ method_field("DELETE") }} is adding a hidden field to the form for this purpose. You may post your blade, route, and controller files to spot the issue.

Comment: By the way, the path you wrote to the form action may match with another route you have defined. comment out all the routes except the delete() route to make sure.

Comment: Ok, This is my code blade file https://codeshare.io/alkoyD   route file https://codeshare.io/Gbwvy7   controller file https://codeshare.io/GLrw0b

Comment: I spotted the issue. The answer is missing a forward slash in script at .attr() method. I updated it.

Comment: original url which display the list of users in table http://127.0.0.1:8000/lists/user

Comment: It means that the form action is not set by the js script. Make sure that jquery.js is coming before the script in the answer. You may use define a section in your template and use section() in blade e.g. @section('custom-js') <script> ... </script> @endsection

Comment: I load the script from external file not included in html file in the link below is the code for master blade page which contain backend layouts as you can see in line 125 i load jQuary and line 145 i load script file. https://codeshare.io/5ZbLrd

Comment: This is the full project files https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B90HFm0P2IoXM05YcmVmVXdQcmM

Comment: userlist.blade.php Line:133 $('#deleteUserForm').attr('action', 'delete/user/' + button.data('user-id'));  ====> $('#deleteUserForm').attr('action', '/delete/user/' + button.data('user-id'));

Comment: userlist.blade.php Line:131 $('#deleteUserForm').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {   ======> $('#deleteUserModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) { //////// P.S. Change your modal's id accordingly. Please make sure that js code is running with adding console.log() into the js block!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have used this method below to make it work but that will need to make a modal for each delete button so i don't think this is a good solution for backend may have more than 1k users or even 200k users so i want this to work when the modal outside the loop ?

```html
@foreach ($users as $user)
<tr>
    <th scope="row">{{ $loop->index + 1 }}</th>
    <td>{{ $user->fullname }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->username }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
    <td>
        @foreach( $roles as $role ) {{ $user->role_id == $role->id ? $role->name : ''}} @endforeach
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="{{ route('dUseInfo', [$user->id]) }}">
            <button type="button" class="btn mr-0 mb-0 btn-outline-primary btn-sm"><i class="icon-settings2"></i></button>
        </a>
        <button type="button" class="btn mr-0 mb-0 btn-outline-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#iconModal-{{ $user->id }}"><i class="icon-trash3"></i></button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade text-xs-left" id="iconModal-{{ $user->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2"><i class="icon-warning2"></i> Confirmation Message</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Are you sure that you want to <strong>Delete</strong> this user ?</p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        {!! Form::open(['route' => ['deleteUser', $user->id], 'class' => 'delete', 'method' => 'DELETE']) !!}
                        <button type="button" class="btn grey btn-outline-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Delete</button>

                        {!! Form::close() !!}

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```